# ReSharper configuration error for href

Tags: html, resharper

I am new to ReSharper and have not fully figured out how to configure it yet.  I get a warning on the following code segment and was wondering how to fix the problem.

```
<li><a href="#/files">Files</a></li>
<li><a href="#/estimates">Estimates</a></li>
<li><a href="#/reports">Reports</a></li>
```

It wants me to remove the `href` reference.  This is a SPA application and the `#/xxx` points to the directory under views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ReSharper's default configuration, you'll get the "Unknown ID" warning which is displayed for references without a corresponding element with an `id="someid"`.

If this inspection generates too much false-positives in your SPA, you could change it's severity for example to "Hint" in the settings, and save it to the "solution team shared settings".

[image]